# How do I cite a line of poetry that is repeated throughout the poem? Should I just cite the first time it occurs?

Tags: poetry, citation

The line is repeated several times throughout the poem

Comment: Unless the poem is an epic over 50 pages, I would just cite the poem and not worry about referencing a particular line.

Comment: If you have to name a line, name the first one and then type _et passim_ afterwards. That means it appears elsewhere afterwards.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some more context? For example, are you citing the line of poetry in an essay, or is it an article for a magazine? What is the topic of the writing -- literary analysis on the poem? Or using the quoted line of poetry as an example? Depending on how formal vs informal the context is, that affects how you cite poems -- both inside the text, and in the Works Cited or the Bibliography.

Comment: It is for an essay. I am just looking for the in-text citation.